# Why is the planned Kingdom Tower Skydeck unsuitable for use as a helipad?

Tags: landing, helicopter, wind, helipad

Why is the planned [Kingdom Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_Tower) Skydeck unsuitable for use as a helipad? Originally the skydeck was supposed to be a helipad, but this idea was subsequently rejected and the feature was repurposed as a "sky deck" when it was discovered that it was not usable as a helipad, recalling another failed aviation docking boondoggle, the airship mooring mast on the [Empire State Building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empire_State_Building).

[image]
[image]

Comment: My brain had a very hard time processing that right hand image. At first I thought it was a closeup of the rotor folding mechanism of some helicopter, and I couldn't figure out why it was included. I now realize that it's a top-down view of the building, but my brain still doesn't want to go there - it still looks like a closeup of some mechanical device. /totally off-topic.

Comment: This just another case of an engineer destroying the dreams of an architect with reality.

Comment: Changes in wind speed/direction always cause turbulence and swirl around buildings which are unanticipated and random.  I'm amazed that they didn't ask a helicopter pilot before even proposing it.  One look at that and most pilots would laugh.

Comment: @FreeMan: _I_ say it looks like some sort of spacecraft docking port.

Answer (score 9):

A quote from The Guardian:

> A Starship Enterprise-like circular helipad, 30m across, protrudes out at level 157. This was originally designed to provide fast access to the penthouse, but **the wind makes it a dangerous place to land**, so instead it has become an observation deck – the world’s highest at 630m.

[link](http://www.theguardian.com/cities/2015/jun/04/jeddahs-kingdom-tower-how-much-higher-can-skyscrapers-go-a-history-of-cities-in-50-buildings-day-50) (emphasis by me)

Helicopter prefers steady wind condition in order to land safely and comfortably. The nature of wind at such height is gusty and turbulent due to proximity to the building itself. It would be unsafe and very uncomfortable to the rich man who rides the chopper for 'quick access' to the penthouse on that floor. The highest helipad now is [at 438 meters high](http://www.ctbuh.org/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=qH7LkIkhjQc%3D) at that is at the TOP of the building.

Comment: Please cite an authoritative source for this statement: "Helicopter prefers steady wind"

Comment: @rbp i will look for good source after this weekend. I will be out of town. My meaning of steady wind is fairly constant wind, not gusty and vary in dirextion and speed wind. That way pilot can make correction for wind velocity. If the wind is unsteady it would be difficult to judge the amount of input needed. I do not mean pilot prefer to have headwind than no wind.

Comment: the reason you can't find an authoritative source is because its not true

Comment: @rbp: I think he means that the _pilot_ prefers that the wind be steady, because it makes it easier to land.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link to the list of highest helipads in the world is now dead.